# how to display text and bind to primary key in MVC 3 comboboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

In MVC3 app, how to display the text (say product name) but at the same time bind the value to its primary key (say product id). here is my html combo box

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ProductId)
        .AutoFill(true)
        .HighlightFirstMatch(true)
        .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("GetProductsyKeyword", "Product")))
```

and the method GetProductsyKeyword returns:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = new SelectList(Products, "Id", "Description") };
```

The above code is ok for a newly created product but not when load and display the data from database as the combo box has no idea how to display the text. please help!

Comment: Does it need to be a Telerik combo box?  I'm not that familiar with this control.  I can help you with some detailed code if you decide to use the normal HTML select element?